# Trying to upload and download Excel and Word docs using Blob storage in Azure ASP.Net (not Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I have tried a number of things on the web with no luck.  Does anyone have working code (I also need to test this running locally before we deploy to the server - eventually a web app)

Looking for working code.

TIA
Mark

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written and the issues you're running with that.

Comment: To add to this, we are using the Teleik upload control.  Maybe this might help.  The code i have is in a disarray so I would be posting garbage.  I would hope someone would have run into this and have code to do this.                               CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(strFilename); name of file
blockBlob.UploadFromStream(file); stream from Telrik control

Comment: Is that you use UI for ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: This is ASP.Net not MVC. I do have all the credentials and that works fine.  All the code I tried to upload and download to/from a blob did not work with Excel files (only type I tried as that Word and PDFs are most of the types used)

Comment: We are using Telerik control and it is working fine now.

Comment: Since your issue has been resolved by yourselves, please post your answer.